# Can Google Source Repository authenticate with Application Default Credentials?

Tags: gcloud, google-source-repositories

I'm attempting to clone a repo hosted on Google Source Repository with Application Default Credentials (i.e. the file at `~/.config/gcloud/ application_default_credentials.json`).

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work:

```
#11 1.030 ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) You do not currently have an active account selected.
#11 1.030 Please run:
#11 1.030
#11 1.030   $ gcloud auth login
#11 1.030
#11 1.030 to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
#11 1.030 different account:
#11 1.030
#11 1.030   $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning the repository using the CLI `gcloud source repos clone yourRepo` you don't need to set credentials ( this is [only needed when using the GCP client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) )

But you need to be logged with an account that has at least the [`source.reader`](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control#roles) role granted.

To check if you are logged run `gcloud auth list`:

- If no accounts are shown run `gcloud auth login yourAccount` to log in.
- If there are accounts shown and you want to change the active account run `gclud config set account yourAccount`